# Changing one property of template in control

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, styles

I have got a datagrid and it has declared

```
ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}"
```

and in this style I have

```
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4" />
```

How can I change padding of header at particular column without changing style?

I need to do it, because at start I have cut headertext, and I need decrease padding to 2 at this column to display full text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another `Style` using `BasedOn` property to re-use the exisitng style:-

```
 <Style x:Key="SpecialDataGridColumnHeaderStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
     <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4" />
 </Style>
```

Now on the specific `DataGridColumn` you can assign this special style to the `HeaderStyle`

```
<DataGridTextColumn ... HeaderStyle="{StaticResource SpecialDataGridColumnHeaderStyle}" />
```